# Base table or view not found Magento

Tags: mysql, database, magento, phpmyadmin

I have installed a new theme called Express (pt_express) from Magento and I am having issues. I keep getting "There is a problem with the reindexing process" when I go to reindex all the files there. The one called "PT Express" (that got created when I made the theme) is the one that cannot be reindexed. When I tried to do it via SSH I got this:

> PT Filter index process unknown error:
>       exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not 
>       found: 1146 Table 'justind1_direct.filter_attribute_url_key' doesn't exist'
>       in /home/justind1/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

However, everything else indexed fine.

I looked in phpMyAdmin and I know the table isn't there, but I don't know how to create it. How do I create this table so it exists?

Answer (score 0):

The table

```
`filter_attribute_url_key`
```

is not part of any stock magento system I've heard of.  That, plus the fact that googling for that table name **only** brings up this ticket, point to this table (and problem) being

1. Part of a module that came with your theme
2. Part of some custom code you have on your system that's interacting poorly with the code that came with your them

I'd look at the modules that came with your theme -- particularly the `sql` folder.  These contain setup resource files (migrations) that should automatically run if you load Magento with an empty cache.  That's normally how modules add new needed tables.

You also might try asking your vendor for support.

Without more research you're unlikely to find an answer here, given the very specific nature of the problem and the known state of your specific system.